# Issue $watch is not firing in converting jquery tree plugin into angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to convert this jquery tree plugin [jqTree](https://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/). Therefore I started as follows.

**Here is the Controller**

```
angular.module('mainApp')
    .controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$window', '$timeout', function($scope, $window, $timeout ){
        $scope.treeData =   [
                              {
                                "label": "Ports",
                                "id": "portRoot",
                                "nodeType": "portRoot",
                                "contextMenu": true,
                                "className": "portIcon",
                                "children": [
                                  {
                                    "label": "bazingaJJRow1",
                                    "id": "portID_3",
                                    "nodeType": "portParent",
                                    "className": "portIcon currentPortStatus ellipses",
                                    "children": [
                                      {
                                        "label": "Stream",
                                        "className": "streamIcon",
                                        "id": "port_stream_3",
                                        "nodeType": "stream",
                                        "contextMenu": true
                                      },
                                      {
                                        "label": "IPV4",
                                        "className": "ipv4Icon",
                                        "id": "port_ipv4_3",
                                        "nodeType": "ipv4",
                                        "contextMenu": true
                                      },
                                      {
                                        "label": "IPV6",
                                        "className": "ipv6Icon",
                                        "id": "port_ipv6_3",
                                        "nodeType": "ipv6",
                                        "contextMenu": true
                                      }                       
                                    ],
                                    "tgenType": "Ixia",
                                    "trafficState": 1,
                                    "contextMenu": true
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "label": "PORT:JJ:Bazinga1:Gi0/1/1",
                                    "id": "portID_8",
                                    "nodeType": "portParent",
                                    "className": "portIcon currentPortStatus ellipses",
                                    "children": [
                                      {
                                        "label": "Stream",
                                        "className": "streamIcon",
                                        "id": "port_stream_8",
                                        "nodeType": "stream",
                                        "contextMenu": true
                                      },
                                      {
                                        "label": "IPV4",
                                        "className": "ipv4Icon",
                                        "id": "port_ipv4_8",
                                        "nodeType": "ipv4",
                                        "contextMenu": true
                                      },
                                      {
                                        "label": "OSPF v2",
                                        "className": "ospfv2Icon",
                                        "id": "port_ospfv2_8",
                                        "nodeType": "ospfv2",
                                        "contextMenu": true
                                      }
                                    ],
                                    "tgenType": "Ixia",
                                    "trafficState": 0,
                                    "contextMenu": true
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "label": "PORT:JJ:Bazinga2:Gi0/2/23",
                                    "id": "portID_10",
                                    "nodeType": "portParent",
                                    "className": "portIcon currentPortStatus ellipses",
                                    "children": [
                                      {
                                        "label": "Stream",
                                        "className": "streamIcon",
                                        "id": "port_stream_10",
                                        "nodeType": "stream",
                                        "contextMenu": true
                                      },
                                      {
                                        "label": "IPV4",
                                        "className": "ipv4Icon",
                                        "id": "port_ipv4_10",
                                        "nodeType": "ipv4",
                                        "contextMenu": true
                                      },
                                      {
                                        "label": "IPV6",
                                        "className": "ipv6Icon",
                                        "id": "port_ipv6_10",
                                        "nodeType": "ipv6",
                                        "contextMenu": true
                                      }
                                    ],
                                    "tgenType": "Spirent",
                                    "trafficState": 0,
                                    "controllerextMenu": true
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            ];

        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.treeData[0].label = "New Port";
        },5000);        
    }]);
```

For testing purpose,here in the controller I am updating the lable on the scope after 5 seconds using $timeout service.

**HTML/ Directive Template**

```
<jq-Tree tree-Data="treeData"></jq-Tree>
```

**Directive Code**

```
angular.module('mainApp')
    .directive('jqTree', ['$window', '$state', '$timeout', function($window, $state, $timeout){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace : true,
            scope : {
                treeData : "="
            },
            template: '<div id="navigationLeft"></div>',
            controller : function jqTreeController($scope){

            },
            link : function jqTreeLink (scope, elem, attrs) {
                elem.on({
                    "tree.click" : function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        console.log("clicked");
                    }
                })
                .tree({
                    data : scope.treeData,
                    slide : false,
                    useContextMenu : false,
                    onCreateLi: function(node, $li) {
                        $li.addClass("list-group-item")
                            .find("span.jqtree-title")
                            .addClass(node.className)
                            .data("primarykey", node.id)
                            .data("uplinkstate", "UP");

                        if(node.insertIcon){ // stats tab
                            $(node.insertIcon).insertBefore($li.find("span.jqtree-title"));
                        }
                        // uplink port up/down arrow icons for corresponding downlink port
                        if(node.nodeType == "portParent"){
                            $("<i class='fa fa-arrow-up text-success fa-uplnk-icon' title='Uplink por status'></i>").insertAfter($li.find("span.jqtree-title"));
                        }
                    }
                });

                scope.$watch('treeData', function (newValue, oldValue) {                    
                    if (newValue !== oldValue) {  //ignore initialization of watcher
                        elem.tree('loadData', newValue);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

The problem I am facing is that even after the timeout is fired, the angular watch method inside the directive is not triggering to update the tree structure. What I am doing wrong here

Comment: Try use `$watchCollection` instead of `$watch`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko still not getting called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) say:

> - The listener is called only when the value from the current `watchExpression` and the previous call to `watchExpression` are not equal (with the exception of the initial run, see below). Inequality is determined according to reference inequality, strict comparison via the `!==` **Javascript** operator, unless `objectEquality == true` (see next point)
> - `When objectEquality == true`, inequality of the `watchExpression` is determined according to the angular.equals function. To save the value of the object for later comparison, the `angular.copy` function is used. This therefore means that watching complex objects will have adverse memory and performance implications.

You need pass third parameter into `$watch` function.

Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/sLvhtrnm/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($timeout) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.treeData = [{
      "label": "Ports",
      "id": "portRoot",
      "nodeType": "portRoot",
      "contextMenu": true,
      "className": "portIcon",
      "children": [{
        "label": "bazingaJJRow1",
        "id": "portID_3",
        "nodeType": "portParent",
        "className": "portIcon currentPortStatus ellipses",
        "children": [{
          "label": "Stream",
          "className": "streamIcon",
          "id": "port_stream_3",
          "nodeType": "stream",
          "contextMenu": true
        }, {
          "label": "IPV4",
          "className": "ipv4Icon",
          "id": "port_ipv4_3",
          "nodeType": "ipv4",
          "contextMenu": true
        }, {
          "label": "IPV6",
          "className": "ipv6Icon",
          "id": "port_ipv6_3",
          "nodeType": "ipv6",
          "contextMenu": true
        }],
        "tgenType": "Ixia",
        "trafficState": 1,
        "contextMenu": true
      }, {
        "label": "PORT:JJ:Bazinga1:Gi0/1/1",
        "id": "portID_8",
        "nodeType": "portParent",
        "className": "portIcon currentPortStatus ellipses",
        "children": [{
          "label": "Stream",
          "className": "streamIcon",
          "id": "port_stream_8",
          "nodeType": "stream",
          "contextMenu": true
        }, {
          "label": "IPV4",
          "className": "ipv4Icon",
          "id": "port_ipv4_8",
          "nodeType": "ipv4",
          "contextMenu": true
        }, {
          "label": "OSPF v2",
          "className": "ospfv2Icon",
          "id": "port_ospfv2_8",
          "nodeType": "ospfv2",
          "contextMenu": true
        }],
        "tgenType": "Ixia",
        "trafficState": 0,
        "contextMenu": true
      }, {
        "label": "PORT:JJ:Bazinga2:Gi0/2/23",
        "id": "portID_10",
        "nodeType": "portParent",
        "className": "portIcon currentPortStatus ellipses",
        "children": [{
          "label": "Stream",
          "className": "streamIcon",
          "id": "port_stream_10",
          "nodeType": "stream",
          "contextMenu": true
        }, {
          "label": "IPV4",
          "className": "ipv4Icon",
          "id": "port_ipv4_10",
          "nodeType": "ipv4",
          "contextMenu": true
        }, {
          "label": "IPV6",
          "className": "ipv6Icon",
          "id": "port_ipv6_10",
          "nodeType": "ipv6",
          "contextMenu": true
        }],
        "tgenType": "Spirent",
        "trafficState": 0,
        "controllerextMenu": true
      }]
    }];

    $timeout(function() {
      console.log('$timeout', vm.treeData[0].label);
      vm.treeData[0].label = "New Port";
    }, 5000);
  })
  .directive('jqTree', [
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          treeData: "="
        },
        template: '<div id="navigationLeft"></div>',
        controller: function jqTreeController($scope) {

        },
        link: function jqTreeLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
          elem.on({
              "tree.click": function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log("clicked");
              }
            })
            .tree({
              data: scope.treeData,
              slide: false,
              useContextMenu: false,
              onCreateLi: function(node, $li) {
                $li.addClass("list-group-item")
                  .find("span.jqtree-title")
                  .addClass(node.className)
                  .data("primarykey", node.id)
                  .data("uplinkstate", "UP");

                if (node.insertIcon) { // stats tab
                  $(node.insertIcon).insertBefore($li.find("span.jqtree-title"));
                }
                // uplink port up/down arrow icons for corresponding downlink port
                if (node.nodeType == "portParent") {
                  $("<i class='fa fa-arrow-up text-success fa-uplnk-icon' title='Uplink por status'></i>").insertAfter($li.find("span.jqtree-title"));
                }
              }
            });

          scope.$watch('treeData', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log('$watchCollection', newValue[0].label);
            if (newValue !== oldValue) { //ignore initialization of watcher
              elem.tree('loadData', newValue);
            }
          }, true);
        }
      };
    }
  ]);;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqtree/1.3.5/tree.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqtree/1.3.5/jqtree.css" />
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    After 5 second ports change to New Port
    <jq-tree tree-data="vm.treeData"></jq-tree>
    Change default root
    <input ng-model="vm.treeData[0].label">
  </div>
</div>
```